# How can I compare the results of an AR Model and a State-Space Model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, mle, state-space

I want to fit a linear regression with an AR(1) error using `arima()` and then rewrite the model into a state-space model using `dlmMLE()` and compare their results. However, I don't know how to obtain the necessary information from the result object of `dlmMLE()`.

The model is as follows:

```
y_{t} = \alpha_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{t} + \eta_{t}
```

where

```
\eta_t = \phi_{1}\eta_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}.
```

The sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data("Nile")
df <- 
  Nile %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(y = as.numeric(x)) %>% 
  mutate(x = rnorm(100))
```

Fit the model using `arima()`:

```
fit.arima <- arima(df$y, order = c(2, 0, 0), include.mean = TRUE, xreg = df$x)
```

Rewrite the model into a state-space model and fit it using `dlmMLE()`:

```
library(dlm)
build <- function(theta) {
  dlmModReg(X = df$x, # explanatory variable x
            dV = exp(theta[1]), # variance of the observation noise
            dW = c(exp(theta[2]), exp(theta[3]))) + # variances of the system noise
    dlmModARMA(ar = theta[4], # coefficient phi_1 of AR(1) error
               sigma2 = exp(theta[5])) # variance of AR(1) error
}

fit.dlm <- dlmMLE(
  df$y, # outcome variable y
  parm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), # Initial Values of 5 Parameters to be Estimated
  build, # Model
  hessian = TRUE
)
```

Now, I want to compare `fit.arima` and `fit.dlm` by looking at the coefficients and standard errors for the explanatory variable x and AR(1) term computed by each function. As for `arima()`, printing the `fit.arima` object automatically gives the desired result, but how can I obtain the corresponding result for `dlmMLE()`?